# How can I sanitise $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and then re-use the query string - PHP

Tags: php, redirect, query-string, xss

On my site I use some PHP to redirect mobile users to separate mobile site:

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {

    // set query string:
    $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    // sanitise:
    $sani_query_string = htmlspecialchars($query_string);

    // if query string empty send to mobile site, else send to mobile site and concatenate query string:
    if (empty($query_string)) {
        header('Location: http://m.mywebsite.com/');
        exit;
    } else {
        header('Location: http://m.mywebsite.com/?'. $sani_query_string);
        exit;
    }

}
```

It's important that if the requested URL contains a query string, it is not removed when mobile traffic is redirected.  For this reason I set the query string as a variable, and sanitise it using 'htmlspecialchars' to avoid XSS attacks. However, this has the adverse affect of converting '&' in the query string to &amp which break the query string eg:

```
?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=ABC
```

becomes:

```
?utm_source=Google&amp;utm_medium=ABC
```

How can I secure my site against XSS attacks without breaking the query string that is concatenated to the redirected URL?

Comment: Wrong tools: `htmlspecialchars` is for insertion into html documents. You're building a url, so you need `urlencode()`.

Comment: No need to sanitize the query string if its just being used again as a query string. Sanitize the data when you actually use it

Comment: You don't need escaping, actually. You want to keep the query string the way it is. Otherwise, you will end up with a single query string parameter with a key equal to the old query string, and no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.

In the end i've just removed the sanitisation as this was unnecessary since I'm not executing the query string values anywhere on the site.

Final code as follows:

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {

    // set query string:
    $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    // if query string empty send to mobile site, else send to mobile site and concatenate query string:
    if (empty($query_string)) {
    header('Location: http://m.mywebsite.com/');
    exit;
    } else {
    header('Location: http://m.mywebsite.com/?'. $query_string);
    exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.  `http_build_query` will `urlencode` for you:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $vars);
$query = http_build_query($vars);
```

Hmmm... But this seems unnecessary.